# Dos batch file - renaming some files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I only know of the basic command lines in DOS.  I've heard that there is a variable you can use to rename files in a directory.  What I have is the following:

> C:\Temp\874540_MyVacation1_x.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\451157_MyVacation2_x.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\874211_MyVacation3_x.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\652120_MyVacation4_x.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\541547_MyVacation5_x.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\321778_MyVacation6_x.jpg

I'm trying to get rid of the first 7 characters, and replace the `x` with `bz`. So that it looks like this:

> C:\Temp\MyVacation1_bz.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\MyVacation2_bz.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\MyVacation3_bz.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\MyVacation4_bz.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\MyVacation5_bz.jpg
>
> C:\Temp\MyVacation6_bz.jpg

I'm sure there's a lot of windows based (freeware) applications that can rename several files at once.  I'm just trying to improve my DOS command knowledge.

I know this is really awful - but can someone point me in the right direction here?

```
@ echo
cd\
c:
cd temp
ren "%[1-9]%_MyVacation%_x.jpg"  ????
```

Comment: If you can, try powershell instead :) Much easier and more powerful.

Comment: There's a simple way using the `_` characters as delimiters - if you really want to rename the format of sample files as listed: including ones like this: `C:\Temp\187645327321778_My Vacation with my dog, spot 6_x.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
@echo off
cd /d c:\temp
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /rx "[0-9]*_MyVacation[0-9]*_x\.jpg") do (
  for /f "delims=_ tokens=2" %A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%A_bz.jpg"
)
```

Comment: Ah, I thought of using substring extraction and replacement but a second `for /f "delims=_"` makes the job certainly easier and is a more elegant way too (if anything can be elegant about batch scripts).

Comment: OK - same request but a different file pattern involved:

C:\Temp\874540_MyVacation1_bob_x.jpg

C:\Temp\451157_MyVacation2_cindy_x.jpg

C:\Temp\874211_MyVacation3_Terri_x.jpg

C:\Temp\652120_MyVacation4_Noel_x.jpg

renamed to:

C:\Temp\MyVacation1_bob_bz.jpg

C:\Temp\MyVacation2_cindy_bz.jpg

C:\Temp\MyVacation3_Terri_bz.jpg

C:\Temp\MyVacation4_Noel_bz.jpg

Answer (score 0):

solution with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
cd /d C:\TEMP
dir /b *.jpg|sed -nr "s/^[0-9]+_([[:alnum:]_]+)x.jpg/ren \"^&\" \"\1bz.jpg\"/ie"
```

---

..output example:

```
C:\Temp>DIR /B *.JPG
451157_MyVacation2_cindy_x.jpg
451157_MyVacation2_x.jpg
874211_MyVacation3_Terri_x.jpg
874211_MyVacation3_x.jpg
874540_MyVacation1_bob_x.jpg
874540_MyVacation1_x.jpg

C:\Temp>dir /b *.jpg|sed -nr "s/^[0-9]+_([[:alnum:]_]+)x.jpg/ren \"^&\" \"\1bz.jpg\"/ie"

C:\Temp>DIR /B *.JPG
MyVacation1_bob_bz.jpg
MyVacation1_bz.jpg
MyVacation2_bz.jpg
MyVacation2_cindy_bz.jpg
MyVacation3_bz.jpg
MyVacation3_Terri_bz.jpg
```